# Postgres. Use parameter value as column idenfier

Tags: postgresql

I'm beginner in Postgres and I'm learning to define functions. I'm trying to construct a function which returns the score in a certain year for each member of a Sport Club. I'd like that the column identifier for the result were the value of the parameter year (e.g 2015) instead of 'ranking' as I defined. I tried to use  `EXECUTE FORMAT`  , but it doesn't work. Thanks for your help

```
CREATE FUNCTION members_ranking(year INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE(name VARCHAR(64), ranking DECIMAL)
AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT name, score
        FROM person p JOIN tournament t ON p.id_member = t.id_member
        WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t_date) = year;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'  VOLATILE;
```

Comment: Functions returning TABLE must have predefined result column names. Did you try aliases? `SELECT r.* FROM members_ranking(2015) AS r(name,ranking2015);`

Comment: No, it's not possible. The function's declaration specifies the column names and that can't be changed. The only ugly workaround would be to use `returns setof record` but then you have to specify the column names explicitly each time you _use_ the function.